# Create drop down menu for every item in a list

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

Ok, so I am trying to create a drop down menu for every item in "$Cots" and move it slightly down. I have the basics of it, well the basic creation for it, but don't know how exactly I would call it using the "controls.add(whatever)" and how the information would link up.

My Code:

```
$Script = @{}; $COTS = @{}
Function CheckProgram {
    Param ($Program)

    # Create Object
    $OutputObj = New-Object -TypeName PSobject

    $OutputObj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Name -Value $Program.Product
    $OutputObj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name LatestVersion -Value $Program.("Latest Version")
    $OutputObj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name SilentInstallSwitches -Value $Program.("Silent Install Switches")
    $OutputObj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name InstallerPath -Value $Program.("Installer Path")
    $OutputObj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name RegistryIdentifier -Value ($Program.Product -replace "[0-9]" -replace "  ","*")

    IF (Test-Path $Program.("Installer Path")) {
        $OutputObj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name InstallerPathValid -Value "Yes"
    } ELSE {
        $OutputObj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name InstallerPathValid -Value "No"
    }
    $OutputObj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name ProductArchitectures -Value $Program.Architecture

    # Populate temporary variable with infomation from registry
    $InstalledProgram = ($COTS.Programs | Where {$_.DisplayName -like $OutputObj.RegistryIdentifier})
    IF ($InstalledProgram) {
        IF ($InstalledProgram.PSPath -like "*Wow6432Node*"){
            $OutputObj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name InstalledArchitecture -Value "x64"
        } ELSE {
            $OutputObj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name InstalledArchitecture -Value "x32"
        }
        $OutputObj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Installed -Value "Yes"
        $OutputObj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name CurrentVersion -Value $InstalledProgram.DisplayVersion
        $OutputObj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name UninstallString -Value $InstalledProgram.UninstallString
    } ELSE {
        $OutputObj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Installed -Value "No"
    }

    # Determine what action should be taken
    IF ($OutputObj.installed -eq "Yes") {
        IF ($OutPutObj.CurrentVersion -le $OutPutObj.LatestVersion) {
            $OutputObj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name InstallAction -Value "Update"
            $OutPutObj.InstallOptions = @("Install","Update","Uninstall","Resinstall","None")
        } ELSEIF ($OutputObj.CurrentVersion -ge $OutputObj.LastestVersion) {
            Write-warning "Installed version of {f} greater than expected."
            $OutputObj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name InstallAction -Value "Error"
            $OutPutObj.InstallOptions = @("None")
        } ELSEIF ($OutputObj.CurrentVersion -eq $OutputObj.Product) {
            $OutputObj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name InstallAction -Value "None"
        }
    } ELSE {
        $OutputObj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name InstallAction -Value "Install"
        $OutPutObj.InstallOptions = @("Install")
    }

# <Example code that doesn't work>
    $OutputObj.ComboBox = New-object System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox
    $OutputObj.ComboBox.Name = ""
    $OutputObj.ComboBox.Items.AddRange($OutPutObj.InstallAction)
    $OutputObj.ComboBox.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0
    $OutputObj.ComboBox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(200,200)
    $OutputObj.ComboBox.Controls.Add($ComboBox)
# </Example code that doesn't work>
    ## Add to list or update ##
    [Array]$Cots.Software += $OutputObj

}
$COTS.Load = Import-csv "$PSScriptRoot\3rdPartyCots.csv"
$COTS.AllInstalled = Get-ChildItem HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\ | Get-ItemProperty
$COTS.AllInstalled += Get-ChildItem HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\ | Get-ItemProperty
IF (Test-path HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\) { $COTS.AllInstalled += Get-ChildItem HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\ | Get-ItemProperty}
$COTS.Programs = ($Cots.AllInstalled | Where {$_.DisplayName -ne $Null -AND $_.SystemComponent -ne "1" -AND $_.ParentKeyName -eq $Null} |Select *).GetEnumerator() | Sort-Object {"$_"}
ForEach ($Cot in $Cots.load) {CheckProgram $Cot}




function MainMenuForm {

#region Import the Assemblies
[reflection.assembly]::loadwithpartialname("System.Drawing") | Out-Null
[reflection.assembly]::loadwithpartialname("System.Windows.Forms") | Out-Null

# Create Forms and Items {
$MainMenu = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$InitialFormWindowState = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.FormWindowState

#Buttons
$HomeButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$ScriptSettingsButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$COTSButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$MicrosoftButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$ConfigureButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$MiscToolsButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button

#Misc Items
$ProgressBar = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ProgressBar
$StatusBar = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.StatusBar

#Tab Control
$TabControl = New-object System.Windows.Forms.TabControl

#Tabs
$HomeTab = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TabPage
$ScriptSettingsTab = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TabPage
$COTSTab = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TabPage
$MicrosoftTab = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TabPage
$ConfigureTab = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TabPage
$MiscToolsTab = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TabPage

$MicrosoftDataGrid = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView
#----------------------------------------------
#Generated Event Script Blocks
#----------------------------------------------
#Unknown
$OnLoad_StateCorrection = { $MainMenu.WindowState = $InitialFormWindowState }
$OnLoad_MicrosoftDataGrid = { LoadMicrosoft }

#Buttons
$HomeButton_OnClick = { $TabControl.SelectTab($HomeTab) }
$ScriptSettingsButton_OnClick = { $TabControl.SelectTab($ScriptSettingsTab) }
$COTSButton_OnClick = {$TabControl.SelectTab($COTSTab)}
$MicrosoftButton_OnClick = {$TabControl.SelectTab($MicrosoftTab)}
$ConfigureButton_OnClick = {$TabControl.SelectTab($ConfigureTab)}
$MiscToolsButton_OnClick = {$TabControl.SelectTab($MiscToolsTab)}

#Load Main Menu
$MainMenu.ClientSize = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(665,474)
$MainMenu.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0
$MainMenu.Name = "MainMenu"
$MainMenu.Text = "Patching Script"
$MainMenu.TopMost = $True

# == Home Button == #
$HomeButton.Name = "HomeButton"
$HomeButton.Text = "Home"
$HomeButton.TabIndex = 2
$HomeButton.UseVisualStyleBackColor = $True
$HomeButton.add_Click($HomeButton_OnClick)
$HomeButton.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0
$HomeButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(12,69)
$HomeButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(100,35)

$MainMenu.Controls.Add($HomeButton)

# == Script Settings Button == #
$ScriptSettingsButton.Name = "ScriptSettingsButton"
$ScriptSettingsButton.Text = "Script Settings"
$ScriptSettingsButton.TabIndex = 3
$ScriptSettingsButton.UseVisualStyleBackColor = $True
$ScriptSettingsButton.add_Click($ScriptSettingsButton_OnClick)
$ScriptSettingsButton.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0
$ScriptSettingsButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(100,35)
$ScriptSettingsButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(12,110)

$MainMenu.Controls.Add($ScriptSettingsButton)

# == COTS Button == #
$COTSButton.Name = "COTSButton"
$COTSButton.Text = "C.O.T.S."
$COTSButton.TabIndex = 4
$COTSButton.UseVisualStyleBackColor = $True
$COTSButton.add_Click($COTSButton_OnClick)
$COTSButton.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0
$COTSButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(100,35)
$COTSButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(12,151)

$MainMenu.Controls.Add($COTSButton)

# == Microsoft Button == #
$MicrosoftButton.Name = "MicrosoftButton"
$MicrosoftButton.Text = "Microsoft Patches"
$MicrosoftButton.TabIndex = 5
$MicrosoftButton.UseVisualStyleBackColor = $True
$MicrosoftButton.add_Click($MicrosoftButton_OnClick)
$MicrosoftButton.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0
$MicrosoftButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(100,35)
$MicrosoftButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(12,192)

$MainMenu.Controls.Add($MicrosoftButton)

# == Configure Button == #
$ConfigureButton.Name = "ConfigureButton"
$ConfigureButton.Text = "Configure Script"
$ConfigureButton.TabIndex = 6
$ConfigureButton.UseVisualStyleBackColor = $True
$ConfigureButton.add_Click($ConfigureButton_OnClick)
$ConfigureButton.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0
$ConfigureButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(12,233)
$ConfigureButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(100,35)

$MainMenu.Controls.Add($ConfigureButton)

# == Misc Tools Button == #
$MiscToolsButton.Name = "MiscToolsButton"
$MiscToolsButton.Text = "Misc Tools"
$MiscToolsButton.TabIndex = 7
$MiscToolsButton.UseVisualStyleBackColor = $True
$MiscToolsButton.add_Click($MiscToolsButton_OnClick)
$MiscToolsButton.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0
$MiscToolsButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(12,274)
$MiscToolsButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(100,35)

$MainMenu.Controls.Add($MiscToolsButton)

# == Tab Control == #
$TabControl.Name = "TabControl"
$TabControl.TabIndex = 4
$TabControl.SelectedIndex = 0
$TabControl.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0
$TabControl.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(124,65)
$TabControl.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(525,375)
$TabControl.visible = $True
$MainMenu.Controls.Add($TabControl)

$TabControl.SizeMode = "Fixed"
$TabControl.ItemSize = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(0, 1)
$TabControl.Appearance = "Buttons"

## Possibly Unneeded Info
#$ScriptSettingsTab.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(4,22)
#$ScriptSettingsTab.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(535,374)

# == Home Tab == #
$HomeTab.Name = "HomeTab"
$HomeTab.Text = "Home"
$HomeTab.TabIndex = 1
$HomeTab.UseVisualStyleBackColor = $True
$HomeTab.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0

$TabControl.Controls.Add($HomeTab)

# == Script Settings Tab == #
$ScriptSettingsTab.Name = "ScriptSettingsTab"
$ScriptSettingsTab.Text = "Home"
$ScriptSettingsTab.TabIndex = 2
$ScriptSettingsTab.UseVisualStyleBackColor = $True
$ScriptSettingsTab.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0
$ScriptSettingsTab.BackColor = [System.Drawing.Color]::CornflowerBlue

$TabControl.Controls.Add($ScriptSettingsTab)

# == C.O.T.S. Tab == #
$COTSTab.Name = "COTSTab"
$COTSTab.Text = "Home"
$COTSTab.TabIndex = 2
$COTSTab.UseVisualStyleBackColor = $True
$COTSTab.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0
$COTSTab.BackColor = [System.Drawing.Color]::Blue

$TabControl.Controls.Add($COTSTab)

# == Microsoft Patches Tab == #
$MicrosoftTab.Name = "MicrosoftTab"
$MicrosoftTab.Text = "Home"
$MicrosoftTab.TabIndex = 2
$MicrosoftTab.UseVisualStyleBackColor = $True
$MicrosoftTab.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0
$MicrosoftTab.BackColor = [System.Drawing.Color]::Green

$TabControl.Controls.Add($MicrosoftTab)
# == Microsoft Data Grid == #
$MicrosoftDataGrid.Name
$MicrosoftDataGrid.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(492,308)
$MicrosoftDataGrid.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0 
$MicrosoftDataGrid.HeaderForeColor = [System.Drawing.Color]::FromArgb(255,0,0,0) 
$MicrosoftDataGrid.Name = "MicrosoftDataGrid" 
$MicrosoftDataGrid.DataMember = "" 
$MicrosoftDataGrid.TabIndex = 0 
$MicrosoftDataGrid.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(13,48)

$MicrosoftDataGrid.autosize = $true
$MicrosoftTab.Controls.Add($MicrosoftDataGrid)

# == Configure Script Tab == #
$ConfigureTab.Name = "ConfigureTab"
$ConfigureTab.Text = "Home"
$ConfigureTab.TabIndex = 2
$ConfigureTab.UseVisualStyleBackColor = $True
$ConfigureTab.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0
$ConfigureTab.BackColor = [System.Drawing.Color]::Red

$TabControl.Controls.Add($ConfigureTab)

# == Misc Tools Tab == #
$MiscToolsTab.Name = "ConfigureTab"
$MiscToolsTab.Text = "Home"
$MiscToolsTab.TabIndex = 2
$MiscToolsTab.UseVisualStyleBackColor = $True
$MiscToolsTab.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0
$MiscToolsTab.BackColor = [System.Drawing.Color]::blue

$TabControl.Controls.Add($MiscToolsTab)

# == Progress Bar == #
$progressBar.Name = "progressBar"
$progressBar.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0
$progressBar.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(589,458)
$progressBar.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,15)
$progressBar.TabIndex = 0

$MainMenu.Controls.Add($progressBar)

# == Status bar == #
$StatusBar.Name = "StatusBar"
$StatusBar.Text = "statusBar1"
$StatusBar.TabIndex = 1
$StatusBar.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(665,18)
$StatusBar.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(0,456)
$StatusBar.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0
$StatusBar.add_PanelClick($statusBar_PanelClick)

$MainMenu.Controls.Add($StatusBar)

# == Save and Open Form == #
$InitialFormWindowState = $MainMenu.WindowState

$MainMenu.add_Load($OnLoad_StateCorrection)
$MainMenu.add_Load($OnLoad_MicrosoftDataGrid)

$MainMenu.ShowDialog()| Out-Null

} #End Function

MainMenuForm
```

Answer (score 3):

First off, you're doing something impossible: on line 6, you state

```
$OutputObj = New-Object -TypeName PSobject
```

and on line 54

```
$OutputObj.ComboBox = New-object System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox
```

You can't assign this new-object to a non-existing property "Combobox" of the object $OutputObj.  Instead, you should go about it like this:

```
# <Example code that does work>
    $ComboBox = New-object System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox
    $ComboBox.Name = ""
    $ComboBox.Items.AddRange($OutPutObj.InstallAction)
    $ComboBox.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0
    $ComboBox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(200,200)
    $OutputObj | Add-Member noteproperty "Combobox" $ComboBox
# </Example code that does work>
```

Similar for InstallOptions -- see the error message you get:
`Property 'InstallOptions' cannot be found on this object; make sure it exists and is settable.
At line:50 char:20`

Actually, if your object has to contain these properties anyway, for your benefit, you could define all properties as `$null` in the beginning of your script:

```
# Create Object
$OutputObj = New-Object -TypeName PSobject
$OutputObj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Name -Value $Program.Product
...
$OutputObj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name RegistryIdentifier -Value ($Program.Product -replace "[0-9]" -replace "  ","*")
$OutputObj | Add-Member NoteProperty "InstallAction" $null
$OutputObj | Add-Member NoteProperty "InstallOptions" $null
$OutputObj | Add-Member NoteProperty "ComboBox" $null
...
```

And then, if they're part of your object, you can use

```
$OutputObj.ComboBox = $ComboBox
$OutputObj.InstallAction = "Install"
...
```

This will make your code more readable, as you can see in this adapted code:

```
# Determine what action should be taken
IF ($OutputObj.installed -eq "Yes") {
    IF ($OutPutObj.CurrentVersion -le $OutPutObj.LatestVersion) {
        $OutputObj.InstallAction = "Update"
        $OutPutObj.InstallOptions = @("Install","Update","Uninstall","Resinstall","None")
    } ELSEIF ($OutputObj.CurrentVersion -ge $OutputObj.LastestVersion) {
        Write-warning "Installed version of {f} greater than expected."
        $OutputObj.InstallAction = "Error"
        $OutPutObj.InstallOptions = @("None")
    } ELSEIF ($OutputObj.CurrentVersion -eq $OutputObj.Product) {
        $OutputObj.InstallAction = "None"
    }
} ELSE {
    $OutputObj.InstallAction = "Install"
    $OutPutObj.InstallOptions = @("Install")
}
```

Once your code is cleaned up and doesn't generate errors, the answer to your question is quite simple.  You add the combobox to any other form control like you did for the rest, in the style of

```
$COTSTab.Controls.Add($YourCustomObject.ComboBox)
```